# Como realizar o fetch das páginas next até se esgotarem

Tags: react

Boa tarde. Tenho o seguinte código

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      pokemonList : [],
      count : 0,
      next : "",
      previous : null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({
        pokemonList: data.results,
        count: data.count,
        next: data.next,
        previous: data.previous
      }))
  }

  render (){
    const {pokemonList} = this.state;
    let number = 1;
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <header>
          <h1>Pokédex</h1>
        </header>
        <h1>
          {pokemonList.map(pkmn => 
            <div className="jumbotron" key={pkmn.name}>
              <h1 class="first">{number++}</h1> 
              <h1 class="second">{pkmn.name}</h1>
            </div>
          )}
        </h1>
      </div>
    )
  };
}

export default App;
```

Se vocês repararem na API, ela possui os valores de next e previous. Eu gostaria de saber como importar todos esses valores de uma só vez, e não somente importar os vinte primeiros.

Comment: `data.next` é um link?

Answer (score 1):

Verificando o link do next da API que você colocou, eu recebi a seguinte URL:

> https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=20&limit=20

Ou seja, é possível passar dois parâmetros via GET que significam o seguinte:

- **offset**: Quantas entradas deve "pular". Por exemplo, se eu colocar `offset=40`, ele vai retornar a partir do resultado 41;
- **limit**: Limita quantos resultados virão em uma página, ou seja, se eu colocar `limit=20`, ele trará um vetor com 20 objetos;

Para resolver o seu problema basta setar um valor muito alto para o `limit`, por exemplo, se você tentar acessar a API da seguinte forma: `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=1000`, ele vai trazer todos os objetos.
É importante lembrar que isso pode fazer a sua aplicação demorar mais para carregar, já que vai ter que carregar uma quantidade muito maior de objetos e para isso que existe o `offset` e o `limit`.